# Receiving "not a function error" when calling the get function from a Map

Tags: typescript

I have the following Map definition.

```
// definition
public mapA = new Map<string,Map<string,number>>(); 

// mapBuiltByService is populated in java and retrieved
// and assigned with ngOnInit.
// Verified contents in mapBuiltByService using console.log
mapA = mapBuiltByService;

// Attempting to retrieve the inner map
const mapInner = mapA.get("key");   // ERROR: get is not a function
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates `mapBuiltByService`? Should you be using `this.mapA`?

Comment: I used a "this" in the code but forgot to put it in the example above. The service code:  Map<String, Map<String, Double>> mapBuiltByService = new Map<String,Map<String,Double>>();   Map<String,Double> mapInner = Map<String,Double>>();    mapInner.put("test", new Double(23.5));    mapBuiltByService.put("key",mappInner);

Comment: Can you please add this to your question, formatted?